# How can I make a stylesheet that counts subcells?

Tags: front-end, dynamic, stylesheet, cells

The example cells in the documentation each have a count of the cells inside their section:

```
 Cell[TextData[{"Basic Examples", "  ", Cell["(4)", "ExampleCount"]}],
   "ExampleSection", "ExampleSection"]
```

But this is static content, how exactly would this work dynamically? I'd like to make my own cell style where the cell dingbat counts the number of cells inside the cell group it contains (and updates itself dynamically of course).

I've looked at the stylesheet for outline-styled notebooks and then tried using the `Counter*` options, but these are for dynamic tallying, not content counting and there's not much documentation on these esoteric front-end things like

```
CounterBoxOptions->{CounterFunction:>CapitalRomanNumeral}]
```

Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Maybe you can setup a Notebook-level `Dynamic` object doing the counting, and just refer to its result at any place you want. (With the help of `CellID`/`CellTags`/etc. maybe.)

Comment: @Silvia Good idea, but I foresee a problem: If a `Dynamic` expression is not visible in the notebook's window (i.e. scrolled out of range) we are out of luck... And having that Dynamic always running impact performance?

Comment: That is why I think a Notebook-level `Dynamic` object (such as `NotebookEventActions`, `NotebookDynamicExpression` or similar) should be used, so as long as the nb is visible, the counter will work. About the performance, I'm sorry but I really can't come up with a way without Dynamic..

Comment: I don't think you can do this with standard `Counters` since you would have to know the counter state before cells that are going to increment it. And it seems the notebook is read by the FE in one direction.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think when it's done each time you save the notebook it should be nice enough :)

```
SetOptions[
 EvaluationNotebook[],
 NotebookEventActions -> {
   {"MenuCommand", "Save"} :> (Scan[
      Module[{nr},
        SelectionMove[#, All, CellGroup, AutoScroll -> False];
        nr = Length @ Select[
           SelectedCells[], 
           Experimental`CellStyleNames[#] === "Input" & (*1*)
        ];
        SetOptions[#, CellDingbat -> "(" <> ToString[nr] <> ")"];
      ] &
      ,
      Cells[CellStyle -> "Section"] (*2*)
   ]),
   PassEventsDown -> True
   }
 ]
```

Ad 1. Cell style to count

Ad 2. Cell style whose parent group end "resets the counter"

You can use it in stylesheets too.

[image]

---

**Update from Question's Author:**

As Kuba's comment fixes the raggedness:

```
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], 
     NotebookEventActions -> {{"MenuCommand", 
         "Save"} :> (Scan[
          Module[{nr}, 
            SelectionMove[#, All, CellGroup, AutoScroll -> False];

            nr = Length@
              Select[SelectedCells[], 
               Experimental`CellStyleNames[#] === 
                 "ItemNumbered" & (*1*)];

            SetOptions[#, 
             CellDingbat -> 
              Cell[BoxData[
                PaneBox[
                 StyleBox[ToString[nr] <> "   ", 
                  RGBColor[0.5, 0.5, 0.67, 0.81], 
                  FontFamily -> "Continuum Light", 15], 
                 Alignment -> Right, ImageSize -> 40]], 
               Background -> White]];] &, 
          Cells[CellStyle -> "Subsection"] (*2*)]), 
       PassEventsDown -> True}]
```

[image]

Comment: This isn't a stylesheet though

Comment: @M.R. I must admit I have not tried but I though it should work as an option to StyleData[Notebook] Cell

Comment: Also it induces unwanted indentations. Maybe we could have a quick chat session

Comment: @M.R. I will try to address your questions later, I have to go offine atm. Do you want to include (5) after the cell content?

Comment: No its just that when the number varies in digit length, the left margins of section cells are all different and look ragged.

Comment: @M.R. We can put some fixed size box there, but what about the fact that such section will have bigger margin than subsection?

Comment: I can't figure out how to set the size of a box like RowBox?

Comment: Also if cell dingbats are really just cells placed horizontally then I don't see why notebooks couldn't have more than one column of cells

Comment: @M.R. sorry, wasn't notified about chat messages. How about `CellDingbat -> ToBoxes@Pane[nr, 80, Alignment -> Right]`?

Comment: works like a charm! should I delete my update to your solution?

Comment: @M.R. you can edit your edit and add new picture with fixes aligned cells :)

Comment: ok, thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Here is a stylesheet solution that gives "Section" cells a dingbat that counts the number of "Input" cells in the section:

```
SetOptions[
    EvaluationNotebook[],
    StyleDefinitions -> Notebook[
        {
        Cell[StyleData[StyleDefinitions -> "Default.nb"]], 
        Cell[StyleData["Input"],
            CounterIncrements -> "CellCount"
        ],
        Cell[StyleData["Notebook"],
            TaggingRules -> "TotalCells" -> Dynamic[Length[Cells[CellStyle -> "Input"]]]
        ],
        Cell[StyleData["Section"], 
            CellDingbat -> Cell @ BoxData @ DynamicBox[
                RowBox[{
                    "(",
                    ToBoxes[
                        AbsoluteCurrentValue[ParentCell[EvaluationCell[]], {TaggingRules, "NextSection"}] - 
                        AbsoluteCurrentValue[ParentCell[EvaluationCell[]], {TaggingRules, "ThisSection"}]
                    ],
                    ")"
                }]
            ], 
            TaggingRules -> {
                "NextSection" -> Dynamic @ Replace[
                    NextCell[CellStyle -> "Section"], 
                    {
                    None :> CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], {TaggingRules, "TotalCells"}], 
                    o_ :> CurrentValue[o, {"CounterValue", "CellCount"}]
                    }
                ],
                "ThisSection" -> Dynamic[CurrentValue[EvaluationCell[], {"CounterValue", "CellCount"}]]}], 
        }, 
        StyleDefinitions -> "PrivateStylesheetFormatting.nb"
    ]
]
```

Note that all the dynamic content might cause the notebook to be laggy.