# How to Build a Drop Down Menu?

Tags: front-end, notebooks

I am new to Mathematica so I am sorry if the question is rudimentary. :)

When I was reading the help page, I noticed that there is a structure like the picture below for the topics in the help page which I call it the **tree form**. The menus open and close by clicking on head arrow things next to the topics. I searched on how to make such a structure in a notebook but I could not find anything. Is there a way to do this? Do they have a formal name? I could not find them in styles!

[image]

Comment: I think you need to read a little bit of docs, here's good start: [/NotebooksAsWolframLanguageExpressions](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NotebooksAsWolframLanguageExpressions.html)

Comment: @Kuba: I already read some documents about notebooks but I couldn't find anything on how to make these structures. Already I know about styles and cells used in a notebook. There was nothing about these drop down menus of titles which I called tree form. :)

Comment: I see, what you need is `ShowCellGroupOpener->True` option which is False by default for Sections and friends, I don't know why :). [**Triangle that collapse cells**](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/57463/5478).  Counts of examples are done manually, but if you need something automatic: [**How can I make a stylesheet that counts subcells?**](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/73375/5478)

Comment: @Kuba: Thanks, I think it is a nice post that you referred.