# Change style of cell if group collapses?

Tags: cells, stylesheet, style

Other than the GroupOpener triangle, are there anyways to change how a cell (that is the parent cell of a group) looks when its group is collapsed or expanded?

Specifically, using the stylesheet could I toggle the background of a cell between White and LightBlue when the group is closed and opened?

[image]

Comment: slightly related: [**73375**](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/73375/5478)

Comment: The only way I can think to do this would be to have a function that scans the Notebook for cell states and restyles open as open, closed as closed.  This would either need to be a manually run process or set to run at some point like when the Notebook is opened.  Would such a solution be of any use to you?

Comment: It would be nice to have Tokens/CurrentValues to handle `CellGroup` related activities :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a style sheet solution:

```
Notebook[
    {
    Cell[StyleData[StyleDefinitions->"Default.nb"]],
    Cell[StyleData["Section"],
        ShowGroupOpener->True,
        CellContext->Cell,
        CellDynamicExpression :> With[{cell = NotebookRead[EvaluationCell[]]},
            NotebookWrite[EvaluationCell[], Cell[""], All];
            NotebookWrite[
                EvaluationNotebook[],
                Cell @ CellGroupData[
                    {
                    Replace[cell,
                        Cell[b_, "Section", ___] :>
                        Cell[b, "Section",
                            CellDynamicExpression:>None,
                            Background->Dynamic[If[open, White, LightBlue]]
                        ]
                    ]
                    },
                    Dynamic[open]
                ]
            ];
            FrontEndTokenExecute["MovePrevious"]
        ]
    ]       
    },
    Saveable->False,WindowSize->{808,689},WindowMargins->{{Automatic,143},{40,Automatic}},
    FrontEndVersion->"10.3 for Mac OS X x86 (32-bit, 64-bit Kernel) (December 10, 2015)",
    StyleDefinitions->"PrivateStylesheetFormatting.nb"
];
NotebookPut @ %;
```

The first [`NotebookWrite`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NotebookWrite.html) is a hack so that the second [`NotebookWrite`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NotebookWrite.html) actually does what I want, which is to create a [`CellGroupData`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CellGroupData.html) object with a [`Dynamic`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dynamic.html) in it's second argument.

Comment: @Kuba It works for me in 10.3 and 11.1 on OS X. Did you add additional cells below the "Section" cell and then close the group? If so, could you NotebookRead the cell group and tell me what you get?

Comment: Sorry, something must have interfered earlier, now everything works as expected. +1

Comment: There is no CellDynamicExpression because I insert CellDynamicExpression:>None explicitly. And it works without children, although naively one wouldn't expect it to.

Comment: Ok, I don't have time to investigate  and somehow sometimes I run into problems. Will delete comments and reply if I trace this.

Comment: Fascinating code!  Off hand do you have an idea of the overhead that this method will incur in larger Notebooks?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I think the overhead should be minimal. After the Section is created, the CellDynamicExpression used to create the dynamic variable controlling the background color is disabled. The dynamic controlling the background color only gets activated when the cell group is opened or closed.

Answer (score 4):

I haven't figured out how to do this with *styles* yet but I feel as though I have made significant progress and I want to share it.  Please try:

```
t1 = True;

Notebook[{Cell[
    CellGroupData[{
      Cell["Parent", "Section", 
        Background -> Dynamic[If[t1, LightRed, LightBlue]]], 
      Cell["Fee", "Subsection"],
      Cell["Fi", "Subsection"],
      Cell["Fo", "Subsection"],
      Cell["Fum", "Subsection"]
    }, Dynamic[t1]]
]}] // NotebookPut
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: @kglr (1) my first version was changing the content rather than the background, but I realized(?) that user5601 probably didn't want that and was only using the cell names for illustration.  (2) With your code in 10.1.0 I get errors instead of "Open" or "Closed" -- don't we need a `BoxData` expression?  I mean like http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/revisions/139083/1

Comment: the code in my deleted comment does not give errors in V9, but it does not update the content (content stays "Open"). With `BoxData` + `DynamicBox` it does toggle  the content.

Comment: Very neat! FYI it's not `True`/`False` but `Open`/`Closed` now (now = v12.1).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a starting point. I have yet to find out how to detect cell group state without `NotebookRead` it.

So place this code below e.g. a `Section` cell and evaluate. You can incorporate it in a stylesheet too, but it isn't ready for that imo.

```
SetOptions[
    PreviousCell[]
  , "ShowGroupOpener" -> False
  , Background -> Red
  , CellDingbat -> Cell[
        BoxData@ToBoxes@EventHandler[Dynamic@Opener[]
          , {
            "MouseClicked" :> With[{ec = EvaluationCell[]}
              , SelectionMove[ec, All, Cell]
              ; FrontEndExecute@FrontEndToken[ec, "OpenCloseGroup"]
              ; SetOptions[ParentCell@ec, Background -> (
                    CurrentValue[ParentCell[ec], Background] /. 
                        {Red -> Blue, Blue -> Red})
                ]
             ]
           , PassEventsDown -> True
          }
        ]
      , Background -> None
    ]
]
```